# How do I stop splitting my editor in Spyder?

Tags: editor, spyder

I accidentally used 'vertical split' and 'horizontal split' in the Spyder editor (View->Window Layouts->Vertical split DON'T CLICK THIS!), now there is no way for me to go back. Does anyone know how to unsplit windows in Spyder?

Answer (score 16):

Never mind, I found the answer when looking at the keyboard shortcuts (as that's how I accidentally split the screen the first way): <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

Comment: Warning to the stupid people like me: it's ALT not CTRL! I know the answer is correct, but my muscle memory and my distracted brain used CTRL SHIFT W and I closed all the files.

Answer (score 3):

I was having trouble with an older version of Spyder v4 on Mac, and I got it to work by updating to Spyder v4.2.1, right-clicking on the tabs in the panel I wanted to close, and then clicking "Close this panel" closed the split panel.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> didn't work for me. It turned out, that I had too many tabs open. After I closed all of them and then right clicked and choose "Close this Panel" it worked.